# Firestore query results problem (sometimes results contain continuing docs sometimes irrelevant results)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have users collection and six docs. Each doc has a  String displayname field.
My users displaynames

1. "aaaa bbbb"
2. "ahmet mehmet"
3. "asdf"
4. "bengu"
5. "berktug"
6. "cagdas"

```
final usersRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users');

  handleSearch(String query) {
    Future<QuerySnapshot> users = usersRef
        .where("displayName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query.toLowerCase())
        .getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      searchResultsFuture = users;
    });
  }
```

- when the query="aaaa" the users has 6 snapshots.(all users)
- when the query="bengu" the users has 3 snapshot("bengu",
  "berktug","cagdas")
- when the query="mehmet" the users has not any snapshot.(my first user
  displayname is "ahmet mehmet")

Firestore query results, sometimes contain continuing docs, sometimes irrelevant results). actually the displaynames contain some turkish chars but i changed it to solve the problem. but i dont.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you get are the correct ones: your query compares the entire string `query.toLowerCase()` to the entire values of the `displayName` field in your Firestore database. The query does not compare any substring of either the `query.toLowerCase()` value or the `displayName` field value.

In the case of the `mehmet` value, there is no document matching the query since, in alphabetical order, `mehmet` is after `cagdas`.

If you try with query="ahmet mehmet" you will get 5 results.

---

If you are looking for a full-text search mechanism, have a look at this documentation [item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) or at this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444).